# Adjust font size XSL-FO with Apache FOP

Tags: xslt, fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop, docbook

I have the following Docbook 5.1 document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="5.1">
    <info>
        <title>Test</title>
    </info>
    <chapter>
        <title>Switchs of <systemitem class="domainname">corp.net</systemitem></title>
        <para>
            Switchs: <systemitem class="fqdomainname">switch-<replaceable>id</replaceable>.corp.net</systemitem>.
        </para>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

And I use the following customization stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl-ns/current/fo/profile-docbook.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="monospace.font.family">Liberation Mono</xsl:param>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="monospace.properties">
        <!-- XXX -->
    </xsl:attribute-set>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, the monospace font I use is too large, so I want to reduce
it down to 85% of the serif font's size.

The first thing I tried was

```
<xsl:attribute name="font-size">0.85em</xsl:attribute>
```

It worked well except when there is nested monospaced text. In this case, the inner one
is too small.

Then I tried

```
<xsl:attribute name="font-size">
    <xsl:value-of select="$body.font.master * 0.85"/>
    <xsl:text>pt</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

It doesn't work when the monospaced text is "inside" a larger sized text (eg. titles).

I've read http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.78.1/doc/fo/monospace.properties.html, that recommends to use `font-size-adjust`, but FOP 2.3 doesn't support it.

Is there a way to simulate the `font-size-adjust` behavior ?

Comment: Can you make a separate template for nested monospace that uses the `monospace.properties` attribute set but also sets `font-size` to 1em or 0.95em or whatever proportion works for you?

Comment: @TonyGraham I'm not sure if I understand your comment but if I make a template that match only nested monospace elements to apply them a `1em` size, I will have to know every monospace element (`egrep '<xsl:call-template name="inline.(italic|bold)?monoseq"/?>' inline.xsl` yields 36 occurences + block elements) and I fear it won't be easily maintainable. I will probably end up doing this but isn't there a "simpler" way to do this?